# Opencart: How to pass a javascript variable to controller function as an argument?

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I'm new to this so bear with me and my stupidity. I'm trying to display a list of customers from the database based on the checkbox being checked. My question is, how do I pass the checkbox/checkboxes' id to the controller function as an argument?

Comment: You need to make a http request. Basically you need ANOTHER controller just to handle the `http://yourapp.com/checkboxes?id=5` request

Comment: @slebetman thanks for the quick response. How do I do that? Could you provide a code example?

Comment: I haven't done PHP in 6 years so I'll leave it to someone else to write an answer. You can just google AJAX..

Comment: Is it as simple as passing the selected IDs to the controller? Does the controller you want to use have a function that will return the customers?